# BeautifulSoup 4 - parse a two col table into a dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup 4

I have a big page to parse but I need to find the section

soup.findAll('h2', text='Case details')

I would like to create the following object

details = {'Court:':'nysb'}

How do I find the section then iterate over the next table that is a two col table and have the first col as the key in a hash and the second col as the value?

```
<body>
  <h2>
   Case details
  </h2>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
      Court:
     </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     nysb
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</body>

table = h2_details.find_next_sibling('table')
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'find_next_sibling'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.find_next_sibling()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to find the table following your `H2` tag, then take it from there:

```
h2_details = soup.find('h2', text='Case details')

table = h2_details.find_next_sibling('table')

details = {}
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    cells = row.find_all('td', limit=2)
    details[cells[0].string] = cells[1].string
```

I used `.string` here, assuming that each table cell contains only text (no markup). If there is markup, perhaps you want to use `''.join(cells[0].stripped_strings)` and `''.join(cells[1].stripped_strings)` instead.

Comment: Hi..I added the error I get when I ran the code in the bottom if the question.  Here is how I import -> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: @Tampa: Sorry, missed that you were using `.findAll()`; either use `.find()` or loop over `h2_details` and run the table search for each match.